# Insertion Sort for a string

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, insertion-sort

I'm fairly new to coding and I'm trying to alphabetize a single string from an array of strings using an insertion sort. Any help would be deeply appreciated. 
The input is "alpha" or s[5]; I expect "aahlp". My code currently prints out "alpha".

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String[]s = new String[] {"bob", "charlie", "mike", 
                             "lola", "arnold","alpha"};

    sort(s[5]);
}

public static void sort(String s)
{
    String temp = null;
    for(int i = 1; i<s.length(); i++)
    {
        char next= s.charAt(i);

        int j=i;
        while (j > 0 && s.charAt(j-1)>next) 
        { 
            temp = s.substring(0, i) + s.charAt(j-1) + s.substring(i+1);
            System.out.println(temp);
            j--;
        }

        //this is where the problem seems to be happening:
        temp= s.substring(0,i)+next+s.substring(i+1);
        s=temp;
    }
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: How about some inputs, expected results, and the actual (incorrect?) results your code is currently producing?

Comment: what does `alphabetize a single string from an array of strings` mean ?

Comment: I.E. "dcba" alphabetized is "abcd". Later in development I will use a for loop to sort the whole String[] s; for the time being, I want to be able to sort one element in s- that element being s[5] or "alpha".

Comment: I'd change your approach, given String is immutable, first get its characters with toCharArray(), do you algorithm stuff on the array, then make the resultant string at the end using new String(sortedCharArray)

Comment: Since strings are immutable, do not do your sort on a String itself. Do a sort on `char[] chars` you can get as `String#toCharArray()`, and then return `new String(chars)`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `String` is immutable, you cannot really sort it. However, you can obtain the underlying char array and sort that and then create a new `String` from it.

If your exercise is to implement such a sort algorithm yourself, then you can do something like this:

```
public class StringSort {
    public static String insertionSort(String s) {
        return new String(insertionSort(s.toCharArray()));
    }

    private static String insertionSort(char[] array) {
        int len = array.length;

        for (int i = len - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            if (array[i] < array[i - 1]) {
                swap(array, i, i - 1);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 2; i < len; i++) {
            char temp = array[i];
            int j = i;
            while (temp < array[j - 1]) {
                array[j] = array[j - 1];
                j--;
            }
            array[j] = temp;
        }

        return new String(array);
    }

    private static  void swap(char[] array, int i, int j) {
        char temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "alpha";
        String sSorted = insertionSort(s);
        System.out.println(sSorted);
    }
}
```

However, if you are not required to implement the sorting yourself, then simply using built in sorts will reduce the possibility of error:

```
private static void sort(String s) {
    char[] array = s.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(array);
    System.out.println(new String(array));
}
```

Comment: I'm required to use insertion sort for my homework, or that second method would be the best. Thanks, I didn't know I couldn't change strings. Glad I consulted stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys. I got it working correctly and I was even able to make it sort the whole String array. Here's the code if you were wondering. (This has been edited several times)

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String[]sa = new String[] {"bob", "charlie", "mike", 
                                 "lola", "arnold","alpha", "beta"};
        sort(sa);

        for (int i= 0; i< sa.length; i++)
        System.out.println(sa[i]);

    }

    public static String[] sort(String[] sa)
    {
        //indexing through sa[k] (the string array
        for(int k=0;k<sa.length;k++)
        {

            String s= sa[k];

        char[] adam=s.toCharArray();

        //The actual insertion sort, indexing through s, represented as char[] adam for simplicity
        for(int i = 1; i<adam.length; i++)
        {
            char next= adam[i];

            int j=i;
            //
            while (j > 0 && adam[j-1]>next) 
            { 
                adam[j]=adam[j-1];

                j--;
            }


           adam[j]=next;
           s=sa[k]=String.valueOf(adam);



        }


       //System.out.println(s);

        }

        return sa;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below sort method instead:

```
private static void sort(String s) {
    char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(charArray);
    System.out.println(new String(charArray));
}
```